# JButton not re-enabling upon closing JInternalFrame

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener, jinternalframe

I have made a simple user interface with a JDesktopPane and several JButtons. The program works such that when a button is clicked, a JInternalFrame loads up and the button is disabled to prevent copies of the internal frame from being created. A Cancel button on the JInternalFrame closes the frame and the JButton is enabled again. My code is as follows:

```
adminAddUser addNew = new adminAddUser();
private javax.swing.JButton newUserButton;

private void newUserButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
{                                              
    AdminPane.add(addNew);
    addNew.setVisible(true);
    newUserButton.setEnabled(false);
}
```

The Action Listener for the Cancel button on the adminAddUser class. The dispose() method is used to close the JInternalFrame.

```
private void cancelActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
    int option;

    option = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(rootPane, "Cancel?", "", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

    switch(option)
    {
        case (JOptionPane.YES_OPTION):
            dispose();
            break;

        case (JOptionPane.NO_OPTION):
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

And finally, my handling code for re-enabling the JButton when the internal frame is closed.

```
private void AdminPaneComponentRemoved(java.awt.event.ContainerEvent evt) {                                           
    if(evt.getChild() == addNew)
    {
        newUserButton.setEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

The button re-enables fine when the default close button on the JInternalFrame is clicked, but the Cancel button works once, and upon trying to use it a second time, the JInternalFrame closes, but the JButton does not re-enable. How do I re-enable it?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I'm new to GUI coding for Java.

Comment: Why do you use option pane so freaquently? Create dialogs yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a possible solution.

- Create an `interface` (I only do this, as no not expose the main `JFrame`). Have the `JFrame` form class implement it. It will only have *one* method, `getNewUserButtont();`

  ```
  public interface GetButtonInterface {
      JButton getUserButton();
  } 

  public NewJFrame extends JFrame implements GetButtonInterface {
      private JButton newUserButton;

      @Override
      JButton getUserButton() {
          return newUserButton;
      }
  }
  ```
- Then in your `JInternaFrame` class, it should take a `GetButtonInterface` arg in the constructor. This is so you can get access to the `newUserButton`

  ```
  public AdminAddUser extends JInternalFrame {
      private JButton newUserButton;

      public AdminAddUser(GetButtonInterface gbi) {
          newUserButton = gbi.getUserButton();
      }
  }
  ```
- Now you can do what you want with that button. Every new `AdminAddUser` will use the same instance of the `newUserButton`. So you could 1. Use a [`InternalFrameListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/event/InternalFrameListener.html) and override `internalFrameClosing()` to enable the button when the window is closed. 2. Use the button for the `cancelButtonActionPerrfomed`

  ```
  public AdminAddUser extends JInternalFrame {
      private JButton newUserButton;

      public AdminAddUser(GetButtonInterface gbi) {
          newUserButton = gbi.getUserButton();

          addInternalFrameListener(new InternalFrameAdapter(){
              @Override
              public void internalFrameClosing(InternalFrameEvent e) {
                  newUserButton.setEnabled(true);
              }
          });
      }

      private void cancelButtonActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
          dispose();
          newUserButton.setEnabled(true);
      }
  }
  ```
- When you instantiate a new `AdminAddUser` use pass `NewJFrame.this` to it. Which is an instance of `GetButtonInterface`

  ```
  AdminAddUser addNew = new AdminAddUser(NewJFrame.this);
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand. It seems to me that `adminAddUser` is created only once. In that case you should not use `dispose`since the object will be destroyed and could not be reused.